# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ToManyFields'

Tags: python, tastypie

I've created a BaseResource

```
class BaseResource(ModelResource):

    def wrap_view(self, view):

        @csrf_exempt
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                callback = getattr(self, view)
                return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
            except IntegrityError, e:

                return HttpResponse(e, status=300,
                                    reason='Internal Server error')

        return wrapper

    class Meta:

        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        include_resource_uri = False
        default_format = 'application/json'
        always_return_data = True
        throttle = BaseThrottle(throttle_at=3, timeframe=10,
                                expiration=1)
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(SessionAuthentication(),
                ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
```

There is my resources:

```
class UserResource(BaseResource):

     groups = fields.ToManyFields('GroupResource', 'group')

    class Meta:

        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['password']
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        filtering = {'username': ALL, 'email': ALL}


class GroupResource(BaseResource):

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user') 
    permissions = fields.ToManyFields('PermissionResource','permissions_set', related_name='permission')

    class Meta:

        queryset = Group.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        resource_name = 'group'

class PermissionResource(BaseResource):

    group = fields.ToOneField('GroupResource', 'group_set') 

    class Meta:

        queryset = Permission.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

Im trying to create a Resource for the user that extends BaseResource, but when i make the relations i get the following error:

```
groups = fields.ToManyFields('GroupResource', 'group')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ToManyFields'
```

I've searched but I cant find nothing that can relp me. 
Any clues? What im doing wrong? Everything is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: do you have a file named `fields.py` in your current package?

Comment: No, should I have? I didnt see it in any example :s

Comment: Probably not. Having a file with the same name as an existing module is usually the cause of mysterious errors, and should be avoided. By the way, are you working from a tutorial or something? If so, could you link to it?

Comment: I've been following http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html

Comment: See my answer below and please accept it if addresses your question (I believe it should).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AttributeError` is telling you exactly what's wrong:

For your group resource:

```
class GroupResource(BaseResource):

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user') 
    permissions = fields.ToManyFields('PermissionResource','permissions_set', related_name='permission')
```

You are using `ToManyFields`, which you haven't defined in `GroupResource`, meaning that it would have to come from a super class, starting with BaseResource (where it is not defined), and ModelResource, which is not pasted here.

While you could debug and look for where this method is actually defined, it seems as if the field that you are trying to use is not in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/), but is in the [TastyPie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html) documentation.

You seem to have a typo.  The Django-TastyPie field is actually named [`ToManyField`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tomanyfield).